# using local variable in another button

Tags: c#, string, file, public

There's an error: "The type being set is not compatible with the value representation of the tag."

```
  string fi = null;


        public void reading(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        read_from_folder = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (read_from_folder == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            files_in_folder = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

            foreach (string fi files_in_folder)
            {
                string fi_nam = filese_in_folder.ToString();
                 ...
             }
          }
       }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                DicomDirectory cop = new DicomDirectory(fi);
                 cop.Load(fi);
    }
```

Comment: if the string "fi" is defined outside the method it is not a local variable.  If these to methods are in the same class and "fi" is a member of the class this should work.

Comment: It's not clear where fi is defined. Maybe you should paste more and clearer code :)

Comment: Post some clearer code and a precise error message (if you have one). At first glance, you have a class member variable defined as `string fi;` but you also are using `string fi` as a local in a `foreach` loop. That local is going to hide the member variable, requiring you to refer to the member variable as `this.fi` within the method that offers the competing variable name.

Comment: Can you pick an answer, or if you came up with your own answer, can you post it and mark that as the answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Frederik, the local `fi` hides the class-level member.  But it isn't clear what you expect to be in that variable in the button click handler.

Because you're looping, if you use the class member `fi`, you'll only have the last file referenced.  This probably doesn't make sense.  If you were searching for a match, say, in the loop, and stopping on that match, then un-hiding the class-level `fi` would make sense, and the code you have will work.  What specifically are you trying to do with `fi`?

Also, the for loop you have won't work as listed... should be:

```
//  Missing the 'in'
foreach (string fi in files_in_folder)
```

*** Update ***
In response to your changes in the question, where are you getting this error?  In the button click event?  On which line?  It sounds like a custom internal error to the DicomDirectory object, whatever that is.

Comment: What is a DicomDirectory?  Is that a line in your code, or a third-party object?

Answer (score 0):

fi is declared outside of the functions shown so it should have class scope and not local scope in one function.  This means you should be able to use it in both of your functions function.  This assumes that the two functions you showed are in the same class ("Form1" for example).

You may want to post the class declaration that these functions are contained in also, which will verify that they are in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

fi won't be local, it's going to be global for that class.

What you have there will work.